# iOS Remove sqlite after uninstall app

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an App developed in XCode, the DataBase was made in Sqlite, but when I remove the app from my iOS device, I lost all the information from that DB.
When I install the App again, I have the DB but without information inside.

Can I keep that  file.sqlite (in a cloud)? And when app is reinstalled (download) to use the same file.sqlite and to have the data that I had before in that file.

Comment: If the user uninstalls they should expect to lose everything

Comment: Hi did you found any solutions regarding this?

Comment: Not exactly. The solution is keep storage in some Cloud. In iCloud will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot keep the file.sqlite on the filesystem after your app is uninstalled. As soon as the app is uninstalled the associated data file is also deleted.

Comment: Yes I know that, but, another choice? I need keep my data in the iphone, and when the customer download the app again, shows that information that he had.

Comment: this is not the correct answer and should not be marked as such

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this by synchronizing the SQLIte database with another database stored in the cloud. If you associated the synchronized records with a user account, the next time they use that user account, you can refresh the local database with the server database. It won't matter if they deleted the app or moved to a new phone. You're storing their backup on a server.