# Uninstall and reinstall application will create a new sqlite file every-time? What happens to the old sqlite file on an iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, kik

I want to ask if you uninstall an app and reinstall it again on an iPhone then does it create a new SQLite file every time and the old one gets deleted when you uninstall or delete the app?

If so, what happens to the old SQLite files? do they just sit somewhere in the un-allocated spaces of the drive? Or do they get overwritten every time?

Any way to find these old deleted SQLite files swimming somewhere in the un-allocated space even using forensic tools? I am specifically asking about kik..

Comment: I think this can answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737796/ios-remove-sqlite-after-uninstall-app

Comment: doesnt answer my question completely..

Comment: the files are just deleted when the app is removed. No temporary storage or bin folder

Comment: Can they be traced using forensic analysis? What happens when you reinstall the same app again after deleting the app?